# What does "we have a go plotting in" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

It sounds like the lecturer is [saying](https://youtu.be/w6mdjf4nVTA?t=125)

> going
>   back to a more complex place. let's just
>   talk through what we should expect
>   before we have a go plotting in

`plotting` is easy to understand, the lecturer is going to show a new plot. And so, what does the whole expression "we have a go plotting in" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He says

> have a go **at** plotting in

In this case, *have a go at something* means *attempt, try*:

> Definition of have a go
>   : to try to do something
>   // "I can't get the window open." "Let me have a go (at it)."
>   ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/have%20a%20go))

In other words, "... before we *try* plotting in".

I didn't think you were confused about "plotting **in**", but if you were, it simply means *graphing (the points, function, etc.)*.

Comment: But what does *plotting* ***in*** mean? Without listening to the clip, I would assume it should be *plotting* ***it***. The other doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: I also found that odd. I assumed he omitted plotting in [the points, function, etc].

Comment: Maybe plotting in the figure? The figure is already in there, the speed versus time graph.